# The best word for "falling backwards" in the context

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The situation is: you suddenly see something horrifying in front of you (big spider, poisonous snake, etc.) In terror, you "fall/lunge backwards" while still facing the "horrible being", and you try to crawl backwards from it as fast as possible.

What would be the best word/phrase to fit that "falling backwards" described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to **recoil**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/recoil)

> draw back, as with fear or pain

to **recoil**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/recoil)

> 3. to fall back

As in:

> He recoiled upon seeing the snake in his path.

Comment: Is recoil more of the step back in fear, or fall back in fear?

Comment: fall back dcitation added to my answer.